# how to redirect one domain to another without .htaccess

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, virtualhost

I have two domain for my website (example.ir and example.com). So I've created two virtual host for them (on ubuntu 14.04, apache). I want to redirect example.ir to example.com, so when a user opens the example.ir, he or she will see example.com. How can I do this (except .htaccess)?

Comment: Do you have access to apache server .conf files? Do you want browser address bat to change from `example.ir` to `example.com`?

Comment: @Dusan Yes I have access to apache .conf files.

Comment: Ok. I've found answer to my question : [https://serverfault.com/a/344651](https://serverfault.com/a/344651)